# Android apk project without IDE from command line

Tags: java, android, command-line-interface, apk

I was trying to make a project from terminal 
[with the help of this link](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676).

I'm stuck at this chapter.

> 4. Build the code
>      Now, I recommend to store the project path in a variable:

My problem is this code:

`cd /opt/android-sdk/build-tools/26.0.1/
./aapt package -f -m -J $PROJ/src -M $PROJ/AndroidManifest.xml -S $PROJ/res -I /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar`

I want to use this commands upper but i have not build-tools file after /opt/android-sdk.

What can i do now? I can't continue without doing this.

***Note: I am trying to make apk project from CLI because i have a RaspberryPi and it works slowly.***

Comment: Building an app that way was not particularly practical back when that article was written two years ago. It is less practical today. Install Gradle, create standard Android Gradle build scripts, and use Gradle to build the app. You do not need Android Studio to use Gradle.

Comment: Thanks i will try gradle. So it seems we don't have any solution for this problem.